# Generic type 'Async<OptionType>' requires 1 type argument(s) using AsyncSelect of React Select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am trying to use AsyncSelect from the 'react-select' library as follows:

```js
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async'
```

But I get the following error, when trying to declare my basic props:

```js
type BaseSelectProps = Omit<React.PropsWithRef<AsyncSelect>, 'size' | 'css'>
```

Generic type 'Async' requires 1 type argument(s).

I am not sure what to do here:

Comment: This means your declaration should look something like:
`type BaseSelectProps = Omit<React.PropsWithRef<AsyncSelect<SomeClass>>, 'size' | 'css'>`